# How to get only player name instead of getting all the remaining stuff

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

b=df2.select('player').groupBy("player").count().orderBy('count')
print(b.collect()[2])

Row(player='Gurevich,D', count=47)

Answer (score 0):

```
df. \
    select('player'). \
    dropDuplicates(). \
    rdd. \
    map(lambda k: k.player). \
    collect()
```

The aforementioned will generate a list of unique `player` values - `['abc', 'xyz', 'foo', ...]`.